# Обработать post запрос с json данными на стороне сервера PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

Есть такой вот код:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'engine.php'
    , type:'POST'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , data: $.toJSON(formData)
    , ContentType: 'application/json'
    , success: function (red) {
        alert(red);
    }
});
```

он отправляет на engine.php данные такого вида:

```
{"account":"1","passwd":"2","amount":"3","target":"4"}
```

нужно на стороне сервера посредством php, обработать этот запрос и отослать ответ, поскажите как обработать этот json не помещая его в переменную(при отправке).

Comment: Речь идёт о работе с JSON при отправке формы на сервер или отправке ответа с сервера?

Comment: Отправляется запрос на сервер, в данном случае данные берутся с формы, но далее они будут браться из приложения поэтому сам факт как JSON разобрать

Answer (score 1):

Разобрать JSON на сервере средствами PHP на самом деле не сложно. Для этой цели есть даже стандартная функция [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php).

```
$decodedArray;
if (isset($_POST['JSON_Data']))
{
  $decodedArray=json_decode($_POST['JSON_Data'],true);
}
```

В результате, Вы получите ассоциативный массив, который по своей структуре и содержанию будет в точности соответствовать JSON полученному с клиента.

Если Вы предпочитаете иметь дело с классами, просто опустите второй параметр.

```
$decodedObject;
if (isset($_POST['JSON_Data']))
{
  $decodedObject=json_decode($_POST['JSON_Data']);
}
```

Для того чтобы отправить ответ, сформируйте заголовок и выведите данные, которые необходимо отправить на клиент.

Простейший пример:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
echo("Ok");
```